# How to overlap image shapes in a DX9 shader?

Tags: directx, hlsl

I have 3 texture shapes that I want to overlap with each other but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it. I can easily make additive blending happen through:

`color1 + color2 + color3;`

But I cannot figure out how to do it without the additive effect. I understand I need to do "alpha blending" somehow but I've failed to get past the stage of only finding formulas or code snippets that I cannot apply properly in a DX9 pixel shader.

Answer (score 0):

There are other blending modes, but the basic alpha blending in a shader program is of the form

```
blended = lerp(bottom_layer, top_layer, value)
```

Where `blended` will returns `top_layer` when value equals 1and mix between the two when value is between 0 and 1, and returns the bottom layer when value is 0.
Simply repeat the operation again for blending any additional layer.

The choice for the value depends on the application. For overlapping shapes without mixing colors, use masking shape for the value. For example:

```
blended = lerp( background, color_green, step(length(uv-0.5),0.5));
```

Will draw a green circle on top of background color without color mixing.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by! I could not get the code to work though... I eventually pleased the compiler from errors but I ended up with everything green.

Here's my attempt:

`sampler2D bkd : register(s1);

float4 color;

float4 ps_main(in float2 In : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0 {

float4 background= tex2D(bkd, float2( In.x,In.y));
float uv = 1.0;

float4 blended = lerp( background, color, step(length(uv-0.5),0.5));

return blended;

}

technique tech_main { pass P0 { PixelShader = compile ps_2_a ps_main(); } }`

No idea what I am doing but maybe you can tell? :P

Comment: Wow... Comments was not made for that I see! Sorry about that, my shader code is here :
https://pastebin.com/raw/JbQadQR8